# Join dataframes from character vector in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Wondering how I join several dataframes that have been listed in a character vector in dplyr?

I have tried the following:

```
data_files <-
  tribble(
  ~df_name,
  'dataframe_1',
  'dataframe_2',
  'dataframe_3'
)

joined_dataframes <-
  full_join(!!! rlang::syms(data_files$df_name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to get the value of the datasets for which `mget` can be used

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(data_files$df_name) %>% 
             reduce(full_join)
```

---

A `base R` option is `merge` with `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(data_files$df_name))
```

Comment: Fantastic. Had tried get() without avail, but hadn't come across mget(). Thanks!

Comment: What's the reduce function doing in this case?

Comment: @jimbo  `mget` returns a `list` of datasets (`data.frame` or `tibble`), `reduce/Reduce` does the join and returns a single dataset